# Nested IFs in index match to look up for value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula working like an index match to obtain cost in column AB.

The idea here is I would like the formula to go through all three parameters like in a logic tree. Note: the parameters are varying in my different files so i would like to avoid any hardcoded names like  (IF x = "**CV**" or "**CH**", otherwise "*").

Example:

Q1, what is the Parameter 1? I have a choice between AAA, BBB, CCC and *. I want BBB. Because BBB is listed, proceed with BBB.

Q2, what is the Parameter 2? I have a choice between CH, CP, CU and *. I want CV. Because CV is not listed, proceed with *.

Q3, what is the Parameter 3? I have a choice... (see above)

Q4, what is the Parameter 4? If my product name (column X) contains this value in its name, go for it. Otherwise, go for *.

Q5, what is the Parameter  5? If my product name... (see above)

I hope i explained it clearly. If not, there is a screenshot to show what i meant.

In essence, I tried something like

```
{ = index(x,match(1,(p1),(p2),(p3)...),0)}
```

with some nested if formulas but unfortunately i could not make it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following **named ranges**:

- **Col_P1** being data range of Parameter 1;
- **Col_P2** being data range of Parameter 2;
- **Col_P3** being data range of Parameter 3;
- **Col_P4** being data range of Parameter 4;
- **Col_P5** being data range of Parameter 5;
- **Col_Cost** being data range of all costs;

[image: Named Ranges]

[image: Solution]

The formula you put in Cell `L2` is:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(IF((Col_P1=I2),(Col_P1=I2),(Col_P1="*"))*IF((Col_P2=J2),(Col_P2=J2),(Col_P2="*"))*IF((Col_P3=K2),(Col_P3=K2),(Col_P3="*"))*IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(Col_P4,H2)),ISNUMBER(FIND(Col_P4,H2)),(Col_P4="*"))*IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(Col_P5,H2)),ISNUMBER(FIND(Col_P5,H2)),(Col_P5="*"))*Col_Cost)}
```

> It's an **array formula** which needs to be confirmed by pressing 
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in the formula bar.

The logic is to use **IF** function to compare each parameter within the relevant range, and then multiply the matched result with the corresponding cost and add them up.

So here is the potential problem, **if your criteria is returning multiple matches, the cost will be the total of all matches**.

The aftermath depends on your preference. If for multiple matches you would like to return an **average cost**, you can divide result from the above formula by the result from the following array formula:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(IF((Col_P1=I2),(Col_P1=I2),(Col_P1="*"))*IF((Col_P2=J2),(Col_P2=J2),(Col_P2="*"))*IF((Col_P3=K2),(Col_P3=K2),(Col_P3="*"))*IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(Col_P4,H2)),ISNUMBER(FIND(Col_P4,H2)),(Col_P4="*"))*IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(Col_P5,H2)),ISNUMBER(FIND(Col_P5,H2)),(Col_P5="*")))}
```

which is 90% the same as the first formula but without the last array `Col_Cost`.

**If you want to return the smallest or largest match from multiple matches, please update your post so I can rewrite my solution accordingly.**

Cheers :)